# Formulas for full m-ary trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I am studying for an upcoming Discrete Math exam, and the final section is on trees. I understand the theory, but some of the questions require memorizing several formulas for calculating the number of vertices, internal vertices, and leaves.

The professor mentioned that there are maybe just 2 formulas we should learn and algebraically derive the rest, but I am unsure which 2 I should memorize. Any help would be appreciated!

> n vertices has i = (n – 1)/m internal vertices and l = [(m – 1)n +
>   1]/m leaves i internal vertices has n = mi + 1 vertices and l = (m –
>   1)i + 1 leaves l leaves has n = (ml – 1)/(m – 1) vertices and i = (l –
>   1)/(m – 1) internal vertices

Edit:
n = vertices
m = edges

Comment: Uhm... so regarding **your** course which include trees, you want **us** to give you the most important formulas... ? You will either have to provide a lot more **detailed** information on the content of the course or actually ask the teacher... We can guess "tree Theorems" for page up and page down, without coming close to what you want to know and even less find "the most important 2 of the course".

Comment: Fair point, I have updated with all 6 formulas given.

Comment: Your quote is missing context. What is $m$? Are you talking about an $m$-ary tree?

Comment: Good call. m = number of  edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just memorise $n=mi+1$ and $l=(m-1)i+1$. The other formulae are just re-arrangements of these two.

For example, if you know $l$ and $m$ and you want to find $i$ and $n$ then

$l=(m-1)i+1 \Rightarrow i=\dfrac{l-1}{m-1}$

and

$n=mi+1 \Rightarrow n=\dfrac{m(l-1)}{m-1}+1=\dfrac{ml-m+m-1}{m-1}=\dfrac{ml-1}{m-1}$

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out.